# How does Windows find/discover the Domain Controller when you log in?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

How does Windows find/discover the Domain Controller when you log in?

I've added a new DC to my domain as a backup, but I'm not sure how the computers will know to look for it, as I don't quite understand the process of how Windows domain login works from a protocol point of view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a client system in an Active Directory network find in which site it resides?](http://serverfault.com/questions/486518/how-does-a-client-system-in-an-active-directory-network-find-in-which-site-it-re)

Comment: `How does Windows find/discover the Domain Controller when you log in?` - http://blogs.technet.com/b/arnaud_jumelet/archive/2010/07/05/domain-controller-locator-an-overview.aspx

Comment: @RyanRies My question is not a duplicate of that. I didn't mention the word "sites". I was trying to figure out how a client can find the IP of ANY domain controller in order to log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you promote a domain controller, it's added to the DNS srv records.  If you drill down through the _msdcs section in DNS, you'll see a bunch of stuff that looks like this:

[image]

[This link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/arnaud_jumelet/archive/2010/07/05/domain-controller-locator-an-overview.aspx) joeqwerty included in a comment provides a more detailed description.  An excerpt:

> The first step is to perform the DNS discovery. The client issues a
>   DNS request for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.mockup1.contoso. com The DNS
>   server returns a list of SRV records that match this request. If no
>   records are available, then the domain location fails. The DNS
>   exchange is done as specified in the DNS protocols (RFC 1769 and
>   related RFCs). If target hosts have the same priority, the client
>   select a return SRV record according to weighted pseudorandom order
>   (see RFC2052).
>
> The client then resolves the SRV record to an address, again as
>   specified in the DNS protocols.
>
> Once the address is known, the client sends an LDAP “Ping,” as a way
>   of detecting that the domain controller is in fact handling requests
>   and determining the characteristics of this domain controller. The
>   LDAP “Ping” also known as connectionless LDAP is sent over UDP

Comment: Ahh OK - so I just need to ensure all clients have the backup domain controller set as one of the two DNS servers (i.e. in DHCP or IPv4 NIC settings) and I should be OK?

Comment: You should be okay regardless.  All the (Active Directory Integrated) DNS servers should know about all the domain controllers.

Comment: I really meant allowing people to log in if the primary DC failed... If the backup wasn't a DNS server and/or the clients weren't configured to use it, it would presumably be impossible to log in as the clients wouldn't have a way to "know" there is another DC?

Comment: Yes, you'd need back up DNS as well, so yes, go ahead and set the new DC as a second DNS server on the clients.